# generating a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, arguments, parameter-passing, code-generation

I am using js to generate a webpage, and need to generate a button. The code is mostly working, but when I try to set the onclick attribute, I run into a problem. The onclick attribute is calling a function, and I need to give it an attribute. I have a variable in my code that contains the value I need to give to the function, but i don’t know how to put this value in the parameters. If this doesn’t make sense, it’s probably because I’m not good at explaining things.

Basically, I have:

```
var potato = 5;
var btn = document.createElement(“button”);
btn.setAtribute(“onclick”, “coolFunction(potato);”);
```

When I open the page and go to dev view, the button looks like this:

```
<button onclick=“coolFunction(potato);”>this is a button</button>
```

However, I want the value of potato there, instead of potato itself.

Anny Ideas?

Comment: Try put your `“coolFunction(potato);”` in `` then replace `potato` with `${potato}` (this is how you put variable into a string), because when you put variable in brackets "" like that, it will understand as a string instead of data

Comment: never use setAtrribute to add events. Use `addEventListener` so it should be `btn.addEventListener("click", function () { coolFunction(potato); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var potato = 5;
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.setAttribute('onclick',`coolFunction(${potato});`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also call an anonymous function with onclick:

```
btn.onclick = () => coolFunction(potato)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would forego the inline JS altogether. Add the value of `potato` to [a data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the button, and some text content, and add that to the page.

Next add [an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the button. When the click event on the button is fired it calls the function, and that can grab the value of the data attribute and do something with it. Here I'm just logging the value to the console.

```js
const potato = 5;   
 
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.textContent = 'Click me for potato';
btn.dataset.potato = potato;

document.body.append(btn);

btn.addEventListener('click', coolFunction);

function coolFunction() {
  console.log(this.dataset.potato);
}
```